# Matlab - error using textscan (invalid file identifier)

Tags: matlab

I need to run a script in Matlab (2015b). The critical part of this script is:

```
%Create module to divide up files    
%Import Matlab processed data from Gaus script
        Gaus_import_Name= strcat('MvsL\MvsL_Combined_OutputGaus.csv');
        Summary_gausian_infomration_Name=strcat('MvsL\MvsL_Summary_Gausians_for_individual_proteins.csv');
        %import data files Gaus data
        f1 = fopen (Gaus_import_Name);
        Processed_data1 = textscan(f1, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');
        fclose(f1);
```

"MvsL\MvsL_Combined_OutputGaus.csv" and "MvsL\MvsL_Summary_Gausians_for_individual_proteins.csv" are files that already exist and this script needs to open them. All files needed and the script are in the same folder. After running this script, I get this message:

**Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
Error in Alignment (line 127)
        Processed_data1 = textscan(f1, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');**

I have also tried

```
f1 = fopen (Gaus_import_Name, 'r+');
```

but it did not help.

Do you have any experience with this kind of error?

Comment: Those are relative paths. Where are you running your script from? What is your `pwd`? Is there a folder called `MvsL` listed if you type `ls`? If `fopen` returns `-1` then the files in question aren't where you think they are relative to where you're running your script from.

Comment: It usually means that there is trouble opening up the file, especially if the file can't be found.  Make sure that the path to the file is valid.

Comment: You were right. There was problem with rights and relative paths.